# R - compare columns with rows of two different data frames

Tags: r

I have two data frames. I would like to take a subset of the first data frame considering only the columns for which the first values is equal to the first value of the rows of the second data frame.

Example

Data Frame 1:

```
columns_df1 : a b c d e
```

Data Frame 2:

```
rows_df2 : a c e
```

Subset I would like to obtain:

```
final_columns_df1 = a c e
```

I am stuck on how to compare columns with rows belonging to two different data frames.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: could you do  `dput(columns_df1)` and `dput(rows_df2)` and put the result in your question please?

Comment: you can transform `df2` from `long to wide format` with `spread()`. check [here](https://www.rstudio.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/02/data-wrangling-cheatsheet.pdf) . Then you can just `join` or `subset` or whatever.

Answer (score 0):

Ok. It's a little unclear what you want from your question as you don't provide a full reproducible answer. But I think this is what you're looking for.

```
df1 <- data.frame(a = c(1, 2),
              b = c(3, 4),
              c = c(5, 6),
              d = c(7, 8),
              e = c(9, 10))

df2 <- data.frame(f = c("a", "b"),
              g = c("c", "d"),
              h = c("e", "f"))

final_columns_df1 <- df1[ , names(df1) %in% df2[1, ]]
final_columns_df1
  a c  e
1 1 5  9
2 2 6 10
```